# Gradle error when creating asset packs for Android app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I have followed [the steps here](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-java) to create asset packs for an Android app, except that at step 8 I am receiving the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:assetPackDebugPreBundleTask'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:assetPackFiles'.
   > Could not resolve project :installtime_assetpack.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'assetPackFiles' to configuration 'packElements' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :installtime_assetpack.
```

Gradle is reporting version 6.5. Has something changed that I need to add something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to delete this question, however I figured someone might make the same bone-head error as I did, which was to have the wrong folder name for one of the assets, i.e. I had `installtime_asset_pack` when it should have been `installtime_assetpack`

Answer (score 0):

If you still have same issue just try to rename your `gradle.build` (in folder of your assetpack) to `build.gradle` - it seems stupid but it helped me.
Also you can take a look to a similar file in the `\Intermediate\Android\gradle\assetpacks\install-time\obbassets`, and see what the name of that gradle file.