# Gradle build failure when packaging GooglePAD asset packs in Unreal Engine

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, unreal-engine4, gradle-plugin

I have followed [this guide](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Mobile/Android/Distribution/GooglePlayAssetDeliveryReference/) to implement the GooglePAD plugin in UE 4.27, but I'm met with the following error when I try to package the project for the second time (first time generates the asset packs):

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:assetPackDebugPreBundleTask'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:assetPackFiles'.
   > Could not resolve project :assetpacks:on-demand:OnDemandPack.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'assetPackFiles' to configuration 'packElements' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :assetpacks:on-demand:OnDemandPack.
```

I see that there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69185085/gradle-error-when-creating-asset-packs-for-android-app) here, but their solution doesn't seem to apply to me since I'm certain my folders are properly named. This happens with all 3 of my on-demand packs. The `build.gradle` file inside the asset pack folders is exactly the same as the one included in the guide, though I have tried just writing the pack names as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/native-gamepad#3) to no avail.

What should I do to build successfully with this plugin?